# operating systems

Tags: c

I am trying to use the `fork()` and `wait()` system calls in C++.

My code is really simple. However I get the following error:

```
error C3861: 'fork': identifier not found
```

I have included the following header files. Do I have to include some other headers here? What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
#include<stdafx.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(){

    if(fork()==0)
    {
        printf("from child");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("from parent");
    }
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? On Windows, fork() doesn't work. Try using cygwin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393218/error-c3861-tcsdup-identifier-not-found

-- check here if this can help you somewhat...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork()` is available on posix systems only.  It's certainly not available on windows.   Are you sure your operating system provides fork?

Answer (score 9):

Normally, you also need the following to get `fork()`:

```
 #include <unistd.h>
```

However, you seem to be using Windows and `fork()` isn't available on Windows.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) discusses a Windows work-around.

> One of the largest areas of difference
>   is in the process model. UNIX has
>   fork; Win32 does not. Depending on the
>   use of fork and the code base, Win32
>   has two APIs that can be used:
>   CreateProcess and CreateThread. A UNIX
>   application that forks multiple copies
>   of itself can be reworked in Win32 to
>   have either multiple processes or a
>   single process with multiple threads.
>   If multiple processes are used, there
>   are multiple methods of IPC that can
>   be used to communicate between the
>   processes (and perhaps to update the
>   code and data of the new process to be
>   like the parent, if the functionality
>   that fork provides is needed). For
>   more on IPC, see Interprocess
>   Commuications.